# How can i get the first sequence of numbers of string by php?

Tags: php, extract

my_string = ' (VAT code) Địa chỉ (Address) 034372 350-352 Võ Văn Kiệt, Phường Cô Giang'

My current code =

`preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '',my_string)`

And my current result = 034372350352 and this's wrong output

But i need correct result = 034372

How can I get the first sequence of numbers in string using php?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$my_string  = "(VAT code) Địa chỉ (Address) 034372 350-352 Võ Văn Kiệt, Phường Cô Giang";
$pattern = "/\d+/";
preg_match($pattern, $my_string, $matches);
echo $matches[0]; //Outputs 034372
```

You can use preg_match to do this. If you pass a third argument ($matches) to preg_match it will create an array filled with the results of search and $matches[0] will contain the first instance of text that matched the full pattern.

If there is a chance no numbers will be in the string, you can identify those cases with an if statement like this:

```
if (preg_match($pattern, $my_string, $matches)) {
    echo $matches[0];
}
else {
    echo "No match found";
}
```

See https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

// make a service class or trait or package with a format enum by country could be useful. Also if you add the functionality to implement it into Laravel. 
   
class VatService 
{

    function getVatId(string $hayStack, string $needle = '/\d+/', bool $validateCount = false, $count = 6): string
    {
        return (
                preg_match($needle, $hayStack, $matches) 
            
            && 
            
                (
                        $count == strlen($matches[0])) 
                    && 
                        $validateCount
                ) 
            ? 
                $matches[0] 
            : 
                throw new Exception('VaT number was not found : ' . $count . ' == ' . strlen($matches[0]) . '    ' . $matches[0]
        );
    }
}
```

```
$myString  = '(VAT code) Địa chỉ (Address) 034372 350-352 Võ Văn Kiệt, Phường Cô Giang';

echo getVatId(hayStack: $myString, validateCount: true, count: 6);
```

You were correct, I was on my phone. You should look to put some validation and error handling into this. Maybe the example helps towards that.

Comment: thanks. but result = 1 . $varstring= 'vvv (VAT code) Địa chỉ (Address) 0316172372 350-352 abc xyz';
$varnumber = preg_match("/\d+(\s|$)/", $varstring);
echo $varnumber;